# Multiple linear regression for groups of columns

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, lm

I have a df with individuals id in the 1st col, a response variable (grain yield) in the 2nd col and the following columns are markers data

```
id yield Snp1 Snp2 Snp3 Snp4 Snp5 Snp6
id1 4.5   2    2    0    2    0    2
id2 4.2   0    2    2    2    2    2
id3 4.1   0    2    2    2    2    0
id4 4.9   2    0    0    0    2    0
id5 5.4   0    0    2    2    0    2
id6 3.9   2    2    0    2    0    0
```

What I want to do is to fit a linear model in R with the effect of two groups of Snps, for example: the first group is Snp1 + Snp2 and the second group is Snp4 + Snp5
I don't know how to write the code, but my idea is the following:

```
model <- lm ( yield~ (group1) + (group2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: `model <- lm ( yield~ I(Snp1+Snp2) + I(Snp3+Snp4),data = df)`

Comment: Or maybe this: `model <- lm ( yield~ Snp1*Snp2 + Snp3*Snp4,data = df)`

Comment: Did either of the comments above or the answer below solve your question?  If not, could you clarify so we may continue to help? Thanks.

Comment: @Duck's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is you want to compare regressing group1 to  regressing all columns then try this (and similarly for group2):

```
fm0 <- lm(yield ~., DF[-1])
fm1 <- lm(yield ~ Snp1 + Snp2, DF)
anova(fm1, fm0)
```

### Note

Input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "id yield Snp1 Snp2 Snp3 Snp4 Snp5 Snp6
id1 4.5   2    2    0    2    0    2
id2 4.2   0    2    2    2    2    2
id3 4.1   0    2    2    2    2    0
id4 4.9   2    0    0    0    2    0
id5 5.4   0    0    2    2    0    2
id6 3.9   2    2    0    2    0    0"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```